# How to call functions from another module while Cythonize? ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

it looks like I have errors while importing module from another folder. I'm not able to find what I missed please if anyone will be able to help it would be very appreciated because I'm on this for a while.

*this is **my test.py** where I want to call function from another module:*

```
from raa.commands import functions
import time

start_time = time.time()
functions.foo()
end_time = time.time()

print(end_time - start_time)
```

*and this is my file **functions.py**:*

```
def foo(amount):
    print("Print from foo")
```

When I write the import like this in test.py it gives me this error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'raa.commands.functions' has no attribute 'foo'
```

But if I just wrote the import in **test.py** like this:

```
import functions
```

The error message now is:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I'm also using Cython, I installed the package and create **setup.py** for the exact file:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name='App',
      ext_modules=cythonize('functions.py'))
```

EDIT: My folder file structure:

```
V .
|-> V settings
|   |-> V cli
|-> V __pycache__
|   |-> functions.cpython-39.pyc
|   |-> __init__.cpython-39.pyc
|-> functions.py
|-> setup.py
|-> test.py
|-> __init__.py
```

Comment: Could you post your folder structure?

Comment: @dosas Hi I just edit the question with the folder structure